# gcp cloud speech java client throwing Exception: Task was cancelled

Tags: java, google-cloud-speech

I have a java app using the GCP speech client library that suddenly started throwing an exception: "Task was canceled" on files that took more than 15 minutes. This didn't happen before, has anything changed in the last couple weeks? We updated to the latest version of the client library to no avail :(

Comment: Did anything else change? Size of the data increased? Which methods are you using?

Comment: The file remains the same. We didn't change anything. That's why it struck me as odd. The code looks something like: 
`OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> future
                    = spchClient.longRunningRecognizeAsync(request);
LongRunningRecognizeResponse response = future.get();`

the exception being thrown in the last line. This happens with both the v1 and the v1p1beta1 versions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked around again. Turns out we did upgrade the client version. 1.20.0 v1p1beta1 works fine, 1.22.3 v1p1beta1 throws error, 1.22.3 v1 throws error. We tested this with a file of  1 hr of audio